# proxy with hapi.js and h2o2, connection close

Tags: proxy, hapi.js

I try to configure **hapi.js** to proxy requests from `/{params*}` path to `http://localhost:3000`. It works fine for root **'/'** but when I try call `/login` I receive `Cannot GET /login` and on request I can see `'GET /login HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: localhost:3000\r\nConnection: close\r\n\r\n'`. On my UI server `http://localhost:3000/login` works fine.

this is my proxy configuration

```
proxy: {
    mapUri:  (request, callback) => {

        //loaded from a configuration file

        let url = `http://localhost:3000${request.path}`;

        callback(null, url);
    }
}
```

Anyone know how to configure hapi proxy to pass custom routes?

Comment: Can we see the rest of the route?

Answer (score 0):

Acctually it started to work. This is my current route

```
{ 
    method: 'GET', 
    path: '/{param*}',
    config: {
        handler: {
            proxy: {
                mapUri:  (request, callback) => {
                    let tls = conf.ui.tls;
                    let host = conf.ui.host;
                    let port = conf.ui.port;

                    let url = `${tls ? 'https://' : 'http://'}${host}:${port}${request.path}`;

                    callback(null, url);
                }
            }
        }
    } 
}
```